# Parameter missing for angular copy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi when i am using angular copy for array of object, 1 property is missing after copy.But it is working fine if there is only single object.

i am using angular.copy like below:

```
var collectionFlyoutObject = angular.copy(name);
```

This is the object before copy:

```
TransformationRoadMap:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, isChecked: true]
ValueTouchPoints:{ValueTouchPoints: Array(3), ValueTouchPointsLink: Array(5), isChecked: true}
```

After copy:

```
  TransformationRoadMap:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    ValueTouchPoints:{ValueTouchPoints: Array(3), ValueTouchPointsLink: Array(5), isChecked: true}
```

Here isChecked property is missing for array of object like TransformationRoadMap.

Comment: javascript arrays don't have properties, those are for objects. Try a different format: `{array: [{...}, ..., ...], isChecked: true}`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey any other alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TransformationRoadMap: {isChecked:true, list:(3)[{…}, {…}, {…}]},
ValueTouchPoints:{ValueTouchPoints: Array(3), ValueTouchPointsLink: Array(5), isChecked: true}
```

Use something like this. As javascript array wont support a separate key. You can change it into an object, and include another key called list.